# Troubleshooting Row Limit Change in superset_config.py (superset version2.0.1)

Tags: configuration, apache-superset

I have a question about the row limit in the Superset chart. I have tried to update the row limit in the `superset_config.py` file with `ROW_LIMIT = 80000` and in the `config.py` file with `ROW_LIMIT = 80000`. However, when I check the table chart in Superset, it is still showing the default upper limit of 50,000. My Superset version is 2.0.1.

Is there any step that I am missing to make this change effective? I have included the screenshots of the row limit in the `superset_config.py` and the row limit in the Superset chart. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]